# routing for an embedded device connected to Ubuntu laptop via USB

Tags: debian, routing, firewall, embedded-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I have a device called a [*pocketbeagle*](http://beagleboard.org/pocket) that I have been trying to add to my local network without success. I've tried many things, but none have been completely successful. This didn't look so difficult when I started, but after days of wrangling it unsuccessfully, I must concede that I'm a hopeless idiot. That said, I need help getting this to work.

## local network & background:

A rough sketch of my LAN follows. The 192.168.1.0 network and OPNsense firewall have worked pretty much perfectly for a few years now. I now want to *add* network connectivity between the *pocketbeagle*, and other hosts on the network, and connectivity to the Internet for *pocketbeagle*.

The *pocketbeagle* runs some version of Debian. It has only a single USB interface that provides power and all external communications. It apparently uses [Ethernet-over-USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB) to represent its USB as an Ethernet interface.

*pocketbeagle* fronts two (2) Ethernet interfaces: 192.168.6.2 and 192.168.7.2. According to the documentation, it runs a DHCP server that assigns 192.168.6.1 and 192.168.7.1 to the host machine - in this case the Ubuntu Linux box shown in the diagram below - aka *macbuntupro*. It reserves 192.168.6.2 & *.7.2 for itself. "Out of the box", I was able to initiate `SSH` connections from *macbuntupro* to *pocketbeagle*, but *pocketbeagle* was not able to go any further than that.

Communicating with the *"outside world"* must be done through the *macbuntupro* WiFi interface at 192.168.1.104.

[image: local network]

## on the macbuntupro host:

When I plug *pocketbeagle* into my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop machine (macbuntupro), I can see the following:

#### `ifconfig` macbuntupro

NOTE: I've removed `lo` and the `enp2s0` interfaces & some other details for brevity

```
seamus@MacBuntuPro:~$ ifconfig
enx606405fa813b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

enx606405fa813d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.6.255
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 68:a8:6d:2d:d4:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

#### `route -n` macbuntupro:

```
seamus@MacBuntuPro:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx606405fa813b
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enx606405fa813d
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx606405fa813b
```

NOTE: I am not sure whether the Destination `169.254.0.0` was present when I started.

> ***With this configuration *macbuntupro* can reach all hosts on the 192.168.1.0 network, and it can reach the Internet via the firewall/gateway at 192.168.1.1. All protocols and services work as they should, and name resolution is quick and flawless.***

## on the *pocketbeagle* host via SSH from *macbuntupro*:

*macbuntupro* can connect to *pocketbeagle* via SSH (edited for brevity):

```
seamus@MacBuntuPro:~$ ssh debian@192.168.6.2
Debian GNU/Linux 10
...
debian@192.168.6.2's password: 
...
debian@beaglebone:~$
```

#### `ifconfig` *pocketbeagle*

NOTE: I've removed `lo` and some other details for brevity

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ ifconfig

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

usb1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.6.255
        ether 60:64:05:fa:81:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

#### `route -n` *pocketbeagle*:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb1
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0
```

> ***These default entries in `pocketbeagle` routing table may be appropriate, or even necessary, but when operated with the default routing table on `macbuntupro`, the `pocketbeagle` cannot even reach the WiFi gateway at 192.168.1.104. From `pocketbeagle`, the only IP addresses that can be reached (other than `lo`) are 192.168.6.1 and 192.168.7.1. Clearly, something more is needed.***

## Status, Trials and Errors

With the defaults above, I can initiate `ssh` connections from macbuntupro to *pocketbeagle*. From *pocketbeagle* I can ping 192.168.6.1 and 192.168.7.1 (Ubuntu side of the connections), but nothing beyond that.

I could waste hours detailing everything I've tried. I've had some **limited** success, but none of it has worked **completely**. That is to say I have gained partial connectivity in some trials. It seems to me this is a **routing problem**, and I've tried to solve it with the `route` tool to configure static routes. I did try using `connmanctl` on the *pocketbeagle*, but it erred with an obtuse message that I could not decode.

Network routing is a huge blind spot for me - I've learned at least that much over the past few days. After some research, I thought the "easy" approach was simply to [enable "IP Forwarding"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14058/286615). I edited the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` to enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, then checked:

```
seamus@MacBuntuPro:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

This didn't help - all attempts to reach other hosts **from *pocketbeagle*** were met with `network unreachable` messages. I also checked [`ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW), on *macbuntupro* and confirmed that the firewall was `inactive`.

*pocketbeagle* doesn't have `traceroute` (or `mtr` or `tracepath`), but the fact that I couldn't ping the one-hop-away WiFi at 192.168.1.104 suggested that `ip_forward` would need some "help".

I added this route to *pocketbeagle* & re-tested:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.6.1
# OR, ALTERNATIVELY: 
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.6.1
debian@beaglebone:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.6.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb1
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb1
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0

debian@beaglebone:~$ ping 192.168.1.104
PING 192.168.1.104 (192.168.1.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.104: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.388 ms
...
...
# SUCCESS! 

debian@beaglebone:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 145ms

# FAILURE!
```

It seems that "IP Forwarding" is not working - or it's not doing what I wish it would at least. If I'm forwarding **from** 192.168.6.1 **to** 192.168.1.104, and 192.168.1.104 knows how to get to 192.168.1.1 (and it does), it seems that it would use that for packets that are **forwarded** to it?! This setup also fails in providing a connection from hosts on the 192.169.1.0 network to *pocketbeagle*. Clearly I am missing something.

I was able to advance another half-step by adding a route on the [OPNsense gateway/firewall](https://opnsense.org/):

> to reach network 192.168.6.0/24, go to gateway 192.168.1.104

It's a GUI config, and I cannot reliably translate this to a `route` command. Unfortunately, while this improved things *incrementally*, it was also a partial solution. It allowed *pocketbeagle* to reach the gateway/firewall at 192.168.1.1, but nothing on the Internet. It also allowed connection from hosts on the 192.169.1.0 network to *pocketbeagle*, **BUT** the connections are very fragile & may last only a minute or two! Consequently, I've disabled this route.

I'll stop here, and just re-state my question:

**What routes are needed to allow the *pocketbeagle* to reach the LAN and Internet, and to allow other hosts on the LAN to reach the *pocketbeagle*?**

*ALTERNATIVELY:*

**If I've completely missed the boat with my approach, please suggest a better approach.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that "IP Forwarding" is not working - or it's not doing what I wish it would at least. If I'm forwarding from 192.168.6.1 to 192.168.1.104, and 192.168.1.104 knows how to get to 192.168.1.1 (and it does), it seems that it would use that for packets that are forwarded to it?! This setup also fails in providing a connection from hosts on the 192.169.1.0 network to pocketbeagle. Clearly I am missing something.

Configuring routing in one direction does not automatically imply routing in the opposite direction. So not only does the Pocketbeagle need a route to your LAN, but devices on your LAN explicitly need a route to the Pocketbeagle as well.

Adding the route to OPNsense (the LAN gateway) is indeed one way to achieve that. The most likely reason it's unreliable, however, is that it results in *triangular routing*: packets from LAN to Pocketbeagle go via OPNsense, but packets from Pocketbeagle to LAN do not. This is because the Ubuntu router has a more direct route to the LAN.

Asymmetric routing is not Bad, strictly speaking, but it does mean that the "state tracking" of OPNsense's firewall never sees the responses and never properly marks the state as established, and forgets it after a quick timeout.

So what you might also need is to add a *firewall rule* on the OPNsense router, so that it always allows any traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.6.0/24 and in the opposite direction. And if OPNsense works anything like pfSense, you should select [State type: Sloppy](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/book/firewall/configuring-firewall-rules.html#state-type) for the rule to be compatible with asymmetric routing.

A better way would be to add the same route directly *on each LAN host*, not only on the OPNsense gateway. That way, packets in both directions would just skip OPNsense entirely. The downside of course is that you need to do this manually on each host... but you could try distributing it using the DHCP "Classless Static Routes" option, which many operating systems support.

Comment: That's a v. good road map. I'll select an answer in a day or two, but in the meantime will proceed as you've suggested. Part of the problem (the other part being my ignorance of IP routing in general) is the *nomenclature* business: you can't search for something you don't know the name of. Good assumption re OPNsense - it was forked from pfsense a few years ago.

Comment: I've taken your suggestion to add routes on each LAN host that needs access to 192.168.6.0, and it's working well. Asymmetric routing is clear enough I think. But I'm still confused on Internet access for 192.168.6.0/24. The firewall currently has a rule for IPv4 that allows **all** sources (`*`) into the LAN NIC. I added a **static route** to the firewall config for the *destination* 192.168.6.0/24 using the Ubuntu WiFi as gateway. The static route enables me to successfully ping 192.168.1.1 from 192.168.6.2. But still no Internet. Do I need a firewall rule to replace the route?

Comment: This answer is correct, and I've marked it as the *accepted* answer. As usual, there is more than one way to get something done (especially when it comes to networking it seems!). I used a slightly different method to gain Internet access for the device on the 192.168.6.0/24 network: I used the static route (as stated in my question), and added a NAT rule to the OPNsense firewall to deal with the 192.168.6.0/24 network.